# force:inputField pick list not rendering properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, forceinputfield

When i use force:inputField for pick list type fields the rendering of the values are not happening properly.

[image]

Code:

```
   <div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-has-divider--bottom">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
         <force:inputField class="slds-select" value="{!v.assessment.N2__c}"/>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Do i need to change any styling class attributes to achieve this?